# @Html.DropDownList set selected value dynamic MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use my system to create @ ViewBag Html.DropDownList. For normal classes it works. But I have an ICollection in my model that I am creating dynamically @Html.DropDownList but do not know how to set the value of the item and had to try to make the error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Key'.
```

#### Controller

```
ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica = new SelectList(ListagemPadrao.ListaTipoCaracteristica(), "Key", "Texto");
```

#### Model ItemLPesquisa

```
public class ItemLPesquisa
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}
```

#### List

```
public static IEnumerable<ItemLPesquisa> ListaTipoCaracteristica()
{
    List<ItemLPesquisa> retorno = new List<ItemLPesquisa>();
    retorno.Add(new ItemLPesquisa { Key = 1, Texto = "Data" });
    retorno.Add(new ItemLPesquisa { Key = 2, Texto = "Texto Curto" });
    retorno.Add(new ItemLPesquisa { Key = 3, Texto = "Número Inteiro" });
    retorno.Add(new ItemLPesquisa { Key = 4, Texto = "Número Decimal" });
    return retorno;
}
```

#### View

```
<div class="controls">
    <ul id="PhonesEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
    @if (Model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="ListaProdutoCaracteristica[@linha.ToString()].ProdutoPadraoID" value="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="ListaProdutoCaracteristica[@linha.ToString()].ProdutoPadraoCaracteristicaID" value="3">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => item.TipoCaracteristicaID) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.TipoCaracteristicaID)
                    @Html.DropDownList("item[" + @linha.ToString() + "].TipoCaracteristicaID", 
                        new SelectList((SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica, "Key", "Texto", 2), String.Empty,
                        new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>                    
            </div>
            linha++;
        }
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Error this code

```
@Html.DropDownList("item[" + @linha.ToString() + "].TipoCaracteristicaID", 
  new SelectList((SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica, "Key", "Texto", 2), String.Empty,
  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica` is already a `SelectList` so don't try and create it again (`SelectList` does not have a property names `Key`, only your model does)

Change

```
@Html.DropDownList("item[" + @linha.ToString() + "].TipoCaracteristicaID", 
  new SelectList((SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica, "Key", "Texto", 2),
  String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownList("item[" + @linha.ToString() + "].TipoCaracteristicaID",
  (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica, 
  String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Edit**

The way you are using the helpers to name your controls makes no sense and they will not bind to anything (you do not have a property named `item`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica.Count; i++) {
  // Generate the hidden inputs this way
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListaProdutoCaracteristica[i].ProdutoPadraoID)
  // Generate the drop down this way
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaProdutoCaracteristica[i].TipoCaracteristicaID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica)
}
```

Now if the value of `ListaProdutoCaracteristica[0].TipoCaracteristicaID is say 3, then the third item of your`SelectList`will be selected and display`Número Inteiro`

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("item[" + @linha.ToString() + "].TipoCaracteristicaID",
  (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica, 
  String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })` not set value for item

Comment: My answer was to solve the exception. The way you are using `DropDownList` to truly dreadful and creates `<select name="item[#].TipoCaracteristicaID" ..>` where `#` is the value of `@linha` (whatever that is). In any case you do not have a collection in your model named `item` so this wont bind to anything.  I'll update my answer to solve this.

Comment: @StephenMueche tks your reply. Would somehow work with this and list of objects? Would somehow work with this and list of objects? For  `ListaProdutoCaracteristica` from Main is ICollection Model